# Silk Test - Bitmap not stable exception

Tags: silktest

Has anyone encountered and fixed the "Bitmap not stable exception" or "Bitmap failed to stabilize error" in the Silk Test Workbench tool?

Answer (score 0):

We do :) The only solution we've found is to restart the PC running the test.